# Cropping image without resizing the image's proportions

Tags: css, wordpress, image, crop

I'm trying to crop all of my images in a portfolio so that they are all a uniform size, while keeping their proportions the same and not distorting the image in any way. I'd like to just crop the center of the image.

I'm using Wordpress, but am trying to do this change with CSS. I've gotten all of the images to be square, but they are still being squeezed. Any helpful advice would be great! Thank you!

Here's the CSS I've got so far, and also a link to the site.

```
img.attachment-portfolio-square.wp-post-image { 
background-size:cover;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://doloreswilber.com/home/

Comment: Why not just register a new image size inside of your theme's `functions.php` file, and force a hard crop?

Comment: I'd like the photo to still be the full size when viewing it on it's individual portfolio page. Like on this page for example http://doloreswilber.com/home/portfolio_page/147-pianos/

Comment: But you can tell Wordpress which image to use in your `category.php` template.

Comment: Oh that would be great! Sorry I'm pretty new to this area. Do you know of anything online that goes into more detail what you are describing? Thanks for your help Ben!

Comment: Of course, Wordpress' own documentation... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/